# How to split string with '/' in mysql stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am new to stored procedure. How to split a string with `'/'` and store it in to variable?

I tried the following steps :

```
bm = 5x112.30 / 5x120.45 ;

SET bp1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(bm, '/', 1);
SET bp2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(bm, '/', 2);
```

But bp2 is always same as  bp1. I don't know whats wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it  by creating a  function split(string,delimiter,no). Thi is my code :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION split( str VARCHAR(500), delchar VARCHAR(2), x INT )
RETURNS VARCHAR(500)
BEGIN
RETURN SUBSTR(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delchar, x),
LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delchar, x-1))+IF(x > 1, 2, 1));
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

bp1 =  split('5x112.30 / 5x120.45','/',1);

bp2 =  split('5x112.30 / 5x120.45','/',2);

Answer (score 0):

that's because `bm` = `5x112.30` it has no `/` character

Comment: but how should i validate bp2 ? some case bm  will have  values like 5x112.30 / 5x120.56.

Comment: you want `bp1` = `5x112.30` and `bp2` = `5x120.45 ` ?